# Skip pipe when empty in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

How can I let the pipe work only when there's output in first command? **I'm looking for a workaround for `pick`**.

I've tried `find|xargs -r pick`, but `pick` only receives input from pipe.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found solution: `...|{ read -n1 p; [ -z "$p" ]||pick; }`